# cleaning up c# code which connects to sql database using windows form

Tags: c#, sql

All I would like is for help with putting this code into separate classes as I cant seem to figure it out. I would just like to understand how this would be possible with this set of code.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FinalDatabaseConnection {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {

        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        //if statment dealing with sql queries once button hit
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            lblCompleteItemInfo.Text = ("");
            String source = @"Data Source=WIN10-LAP->HJP\MSSQLSERVER1;Initial Catalog=VisualStudioConnect;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(source);
            con.Open();

            if ((string) cbfunctionSelection.SelectedItem == "Find" && checkBoxPCSearch.Checked) {

                String sqlSelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM Items Where PartCode = @SelectedPartCode";

                var cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlSelectQuery, con);

                SetInsertParameters(cmd);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                SetResponse(dr);
                AllVisible();

            }
            else if  ((string)cbfunctionSelection.SelectedItem == "Find" && checkBoxNameSearch.Checked) {
                 checkBoxPCSearch.Checked = false;
                String sqlSelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM Items Where Name = @SelectedName";

                var cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlSelectQuery, con);

                SetInsertParameters(cmd);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                SetResponse(dr);
                AllVisible();
            }

            if ((String) cbfunctionSelection.SelectedItem == "Add") {
                 checkBoxNameSearch.Checked = false;
                var cmd = new SqlCommand(
                    "INSERT INTO items(Description,Colour,Manufacturer,StockLevel,Name) " +
                    "VALUES ( @Description, @Colour, @Manufacturer, @StockLevel,@Name)", con);
                SetInsertParameters(cmd);
                cmd.ExecuteReader();


            }

            if ((string) cbfunctionSelection.SelectedItem == "Delete") {

                var sqlDeleteQuery = "Delete from items where PartCode =  @SelectedPartCode" ;
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlDeleteQuery, con);
                SetInsertParameters(cmd);
                SqlDataReader myreader;
                myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                myreader.Read();
            }

             if ((string) cbfunctionSelection.SelectedItem == "Edit") {

                var cmd = new SqlCommand("update items SET Description = @Description ,Colour =@Colour ,Manufacturer = @Manufacturer,StockLevel = @StockLevel , Name = @Name where partcode = @SelectedPartCode", con);
                SetInsertParameters(cmd);
                cmd.ExecuteReader();
            }

             else {
                 MessageBox.Show("PLease refrence the helper text box for help i");
             }

            con.Close();
        }
        //setting the response for the find function


        private void SetResponse(SqlDataReader dr) {

            if (dr.Read()) {

                string itemDescription = (dr["Description"].ToString());
                txtColour.Text = itemDescription;

                string itemColour = (dr["Colour"].ToString());
                txtColour.Text = itemColour;

                string itemManufacturer = (dr["Manufacturer"].ToString());
                txtColour.Text = itemManufacturer;

                string itemStockLevel = (dr["StockLevel"].ToString());
                txtColour.Text = itemStockLevel;

                string itemName = (dr["Name"].ToString());
                txtColour.Text = itemName;


                string itemPartCode = (dr["PartCode"].ToString());
                txtColour.Text = itemPartCode;

                lblCompleteItemInfo.Text = ($"The items description is: {itemDescription} " +
                                            $"The items colour is: {itemColour} " +
                                            $"The items Manufacturer is: {itemManufacturer} " +
                                            $"The Items Stock Level is :{itemStockLevel} " +
                                            $"The Items Name is: {itemName} " +
                                            $"The items PartCode is: {itemPartCode} ");    

            }

            else {
                MessageBox.Show("error");

            }
        }
        //applying the values for sql queries through the input in tbox
        private void SetInsertParameters(SqlCommand cmd) {

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", txtDescription.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Colour", txtColour.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Manufacturer", txtManufacturer.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StockLevel", txtStockLevel.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartCode", txtPartCode.Text);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SelectedPartCode", txtPartCodeEnter.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SelectedName", txtNameEnter.Text);
        }


        private void AllVisible() {
           //txtboxes
            txtDescription.Visible = true;
            txtColour.Visible = true;
            txtManufacturer.Visible = true;
            txtStockLevel.Visible = true;
            txtName.Visible = true;
            txtPartCode.Visible = true;
            txtPartCodeEnter.Visible = true;
            txtNameEnter.Visible = true;
             //lbls  
            lblDescription.Visible = true;
            lblColour.Visible = true;
            lblManufacturer.Visible = true;
            lblStockLevel.Visible = true;
            lblName.Visible = true;
            lblPartCode.Visible = true;
            lblNameEnter.Visible = true;
            lblPartCode.Visible = true;
            checkBoxNameSearch.Visible = true;
            checkBoxPCSearch.Visible = true;
        }

        private void cbfunctionSelection_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if ((String) cbfunctionSelection.SelectedItem == "Add" ) {
                AllVisible();

                checkBoxNameSearch.Visible = false;
                checkBoxPCSearch.Visible = false;

                txtPartCodeEnter.Visible = false;
                txtNameEnter.Visible = false;
                txtPartCode.Visible = false;

                lblPartCode.Visible = false;
                lblNameEnter.Visible = false;
                lblPartCode.Visible = false;

                HelpLabel.Text = ("input the details for the item to be added.");
            }
            else if ((String) cbfunctionSelection.SelectedItem == "Find" ) {
                AllVisible();
                txtDescription.Visible = false;
                txtColour.Visible = false;
                txtManufacturer.Visible = false;
                txtStockLevel.Visible = false;
                txtName.Visible = false;
                txtPartCode.Visible = false;

                lblDescription.Visible = false;
                lblColour.Visible = false;
                lblManufacturer.Visible = false;
                lblStockLevel.Visible = false;
                lblName.Visible = false;
                lblPartCode.Visible = false;

                HelpLabel.Text = ("input the Partcode of the item and the information will be displayed.");

            }
            else if ((String) cbfunctionSelection.SelectedItem == "Edit") {
                AllVisible();
                lblPartCode.Visible = false;
                txtPartCode.Visible = false;
                txtNameEnter.Visible = false;
                lblNameEnter.Visible = false;
                checkBoxNameSearch.Visible = false;
                checkBoxPCSearch.Visible = false;
                HelpLabel.Text = ("Input the partcode of the item you would like to edit. Then the Information.");
            }
            else if ((String) cbfunctionSelection.SelectedItem == "Delete") {
                AllVisible();
                txtDescription.Visible = false;
                txtColour.Visible = false;
                txtManufacturer.Visible = false;
                txtStockLevel.Visible = false;
                txtName.Visible = false;
                txtPartCode.Visible = false;
                txtNameEnter.Visible = false;
                checkBoxNameSearch.Visible = false;
                checkBoxPCSearch.Visible = false;

                lblDescription.Visible = false;
                lblColour.Visible = false;
                lblManufacturer.Visible = false;
                lblStockLevel.Visible = false;
                lblName.Visible = false;
                lblPartCode.Visible = false;
                lblNameEnter.Visible = false;
                HelpLabel.Text = ("Input the partcode of the item you would like to delete.");
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            btnDisplayItemTable.Text = ("Refresh items table");
            //This is database connection string
            String source = @"Data Source=WIN10-LAP->HJP\MSSQLSERVER1;Initial Catalog=VisualStudioConnect;Integrated Security=True";

            //this is defining source as variable "con" to be used for SQL connection
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(source);

            //opens connection
            con.Open();
            // just message box
            MessageBox.Show("connected");

            SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From Items",source);
            DataTable dtb1 = new DataTable();
            sqlDa.Fill(dtb1);

            dgv1.DataSource = dtb1;

        }

        private void button1_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            new Form3().Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry apout the formatting still new to stack. I would simply like help cleaning up this code and help with breaking this down to classes. Please explain like im 5 as I am new to c#.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This question is incomplete. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. [Questions should include a description of what the code does](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1226)

Comment: Could you please add the content of the `Form1.Designer.cs`file as well?